# How to run old x86 DOS assembly programs in 64-bits Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, dos

Several years ago I wrote some x86 DOS assembly programs as aid for Batch file programming. The programs are very small; about two or three hundred bytes in .COM version. I am now updating and creating new versions of those programs; however, the .COM or .EXE executable files don't run in 64-bits Windows versions. I need to know *the simplest way* to convert such programs so they run in 64-bits Windows. I know that DosBox may do that, but I need my programs run in Win cmd.exe Batch files. Anybody could help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no simple way.  Converting a program from 16-bit to 32-bit code requires a rewrite.  Shouldn't be too hard if it is only a couple of hundred bytes?

Comment: I use [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) on Windows 7 x64. It's not perfect, but most things just work.

Comment: For simple programs that don't use direct video output or rare interrupt services, you can try the ["MS-DOS Player for Win32-x64 console"](http://homepage3.nifty.com/takeda-toshiya/msdos/).

Comment: @HansPassant: OK. I understand that; however, what I must to rewrite? Could you give me a sample of what I do to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Windows 64-bit will not allow 16-bit programs at all. You have to find another way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756962.aspx

https://superuser.com/a/140956

An x86 emulator was written in Javascript, so emulation would be viable; however I suspect it's much less work to port or rewrite the programs. http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Comment: Yes, thank you; I already know this: `All 16-bit... "applications" should be converted to 32-bit or 64-bit... ones". I am asking for a _solution_ to this problem. So, what exactly I must do to convert my old DOS programs so they run in 64-bits Windows?

Comment: @Aacini, you need to replace the 16-bit instructions with 32-bit or 64-bit ones for a start. I'm not sure how to change from COM to EXE. It might be easier to rewrite the programs in C or some other language.

Comment: @Aacini, you might also be able to find an emulator that you can modify to suit your purposes, unfortunately it seems most want to emulate the OS as well. Here's a list: http://www.thefreecountry.com/emulators/pc.shtml

Comment: You can run Windows XP Mode and share the disk where your programs need to run. Consider creating a ramdisk for this purpose with Imdisk http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk if you don't want to share a physical disk with the virtual machine.